# Refactor this function to reduce its Cognitive Complexity

Tags: javascript, typescript

Trying to understand `Cognitive Complexity`  with the following example. Is it more about reducing codes to its simplest form??

How do I optimize my code and make it more readable. The condition is if the array objects has a property "average", then display a table with **average column** else don't display the **average **column**.**

```
let columns: any[] = []

export const tableHeaders = (arr) => {
    if (arr?.length > 0 && arr?.some(x => x.hasOwnProperty('average'))) {

        if(arr?.some(x => x.average  == "NA"))
        {
            columns = [
                {
                    Header: 'MONTH',
                    accessor: 'date',
                    sortType: (a:any, b:any) => {
                        return (new Date(a.values.date).getTime() < new Date(b.values.date).getTime() ? -1 : 1)
                    }
                },
                {
                    Header: 'TOTAL',
                    accessor: 'total',
                } 
            ]
        }
        else{
            columns = [
                {
                    Header: 'MONTH',
                    accessor: 'date',
                    sortType: (a:any, b:any) => {
                        return (new Date(a.values.date).getTime() < new Date(b.values.date).getTime() ? -1 : 1)
                    }
                },
                {
                    Header: 'TOTAL',
                    accessor: 'total',
                },
                {
                    Header: 'AVERAGE',
                    accessor: 'average',
                }    
            ]
        }
    }
    else
    {
        columns = [
            {
                Header: 'MONTH',
                accessor: 'date',
                sortType: (a:any, b:any) => {
                    return (new Date(a.values.date).getTime() < new Date(b.values.date).getTime() ? -1 : 1)
                }
            },
            {
                Header: 'TOTAL',
                accessor: 'total',
            }  
        ]
    }

    return columns
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a React question..

Comment: But back to the question, I would initialise a columns to an empty array, and then push the columns I need..

Comment: I suspect you ought to work out whether you need to add the average column first, then add the column to the columns array if you need to.

Answer (score 3):

You can initiate `columns` instantly, because the first 2 objects are always the same, regardless of the `if` expression.
Then just re-use your initial `if` expression but with 1 more condition to verify if your averages have any `NA` value to it.

If everything checks out, you can push the 3rd object into the columns array. If not, just return columns as is.

```
let columns: any[] = []

export const tableHeaders = (arr) => {
  columns = [
    {
      Header: 'MONTH',
      accessor: 'date',
      sortType: (a:any, b:any) => {
        return (new Date(a.values.date).getTime() < new Date(b.values.date).getTime() ? -1 : 1)
    },
    {
      Header: 'TOTAL',
      accessor: 'total',
    }];

  // verify if it has averages and none of the averages have NA
  if (arr?.length > 0 && arr?.some(x => x.hasOwnProperty('average') && x.average !== "NA")) {
    columns.push({
      Header: 'AVERAGE',
      accessor: 'average',
    });
  } 

  return columns;
}
```